# A unique key to use in query operations for the view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this view table in sql server and I want to make it a unique key for each record in a separate column.

how I can make it a unique key for each record in a separate column? like index for example

This is the code created the view

```
SELECT     'order' AS type, id AS id, id_customer, amount AS debit, 0 AS credit, order_date AS date, '....' AS description
FROM         dbo.Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT     'receipt' AS type, id AS id, id_customer, 0 AS debit, amount AS credit, receipt_date AS date, 'cash' AS description
FROM         dbo.receipts
```

I am asking this presentation using this code
But I have a problem when there is an invoice and receipt similar id number is repeated each one of them twice so I want a unique key to do the comparison in the following code

```
declare @id_customer int 
;with initial as(
  select *
  from result
  where id_customer= @id_customer
),report as(
  select r.id,[balance]=isnull((select sum(b.debit-b.credit)
               from initial b
               where b.[date]<r.[date]) + r.debit - r.credit ,r.debit-r.credit)
  from initial r
)

 select [Operation type] = type,
        reference_no = r.id,
        [description],
        [Debit] = debit,
        [Credit] = credit,
        [Balance] = b.balance
 from result r
 inner join report b on b.id = r.id
 where r.id_customer = @id_customer
 order by r.[date]
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Are you asking for a row number? Otherwise, we can't tell you how to make a key without understanding the data.

Comment: Make what a unique key? Are you just trying to get a unique value for each row? You could use NEWID().

Comment: yes sir that what I mean.

Comment: What data do you want to understand?

Comment: You want a unique value or a row number? If you want a row number you can use ROW_NUMBER https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql or for a unique value you could use newid. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql

Comment: If `id` is the primary key column in the `Orders` and `Receipts` table, are not the combination of the `type` and `id` columns in this view a "unique key"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to distinguish your records with a new unique key (as I understand) then you shall use the NEWID for your selection in order to have a unique key for the UnionAll query:

```
declare @id_customer int 
;with initial as(
  select *
  from result
  where id_customer= @id_customer
),report as(
  select r.id,[balance]=isnull((select sum(b.debit-b.credit)
               from initial b
               where b.[date]<r.[date]) + r.debit - r.credit ,r.debit-r.credit)
  from initial r
)

 select NEWID(), -- this is a new generated unique key
        [Operation type] = type,
        reference_no = r.id,
        [description],
        [Debit] = debit,
        [Credit] = credit,
        [Balance] = b.balance
 from result r
 inner join report b on b.id = r.id
 where r.id_customer = @id_customer
 order by r.[date]
```

Comment: sir I want to replace the id by new key .`b.id = r.id`